# java.security.AccessControlException when sending JMS message in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, jms, tibco-ems

I am trying to send a JMS message to tibco designer using GAE. Here are my codes:

```
try{
        Connection connection = null;           
        Session session = null;
        MessageProducer msgProducer = null;
        Destination destination = null;
        String userName = null;
        String password = null;
        String destName = "q.message";

        TextMessage msg = null;

        ConnectionFactory factory = new TibjmsConnectionFactory("localhost");

        connection = factory.createConnection(userName, password);

        /* create the session */
        session = connection.createSession(false, javax.jms.Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        /* create the destination */
        destination = session.createQueue(destName);
        //replyDestination = session.createTopic("reply.topic");
        /* create the producer */
        msgProducer = session.createProducer(null); //changed for request-reply
        //replyConsumer = session.createConsumer(replyDestination); //for request-reply

        /* start the connection */
        connection.start();

        /* create text message */
        msg = session.createTextMessage();
        /* set message text */
        msg.setText(message);
        //msg.setJMSReplyTo(replyDestination); //for request-reply

        /* publish message */
        msgProducer.send(destination, msg);   //Send XML message to destination

        }catch(JMSException e){
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
```

However, after running this web application, i got the following error:

```
Nov 10, 2013 11:04:36 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: /process_message.do
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission     modifyThreadGroup)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:374)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:549)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:383)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkAccess(DevAppServerFactory.java:408)
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(ThreadGroup.java:299)
at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:336)
at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:434)
at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxLinkTcp$Pinger.<init>(TibjmsxLinkTcp.java:142)
at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxLinkTcp._createPinger(TibjmsxLinkTcp.java:223)
at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxLinkTcp._doHandshake(TibjmsxLinkTcp.java:900)
at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxLinkTcp.connect(TibjmsxLinkTcp.java:923)
at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnection._create(TibjmsConnection.java:1299)
at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnection.<init>(TibjmsConnection.java:4155)
at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxCFImpl._createImpl(TibjmsxCFImpl.java:209)
at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxCFImpl._createConnection(TibjmsxCFImpl.java:253)
at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnectionFactory.createConnection(TibjmsConnectionFactory.java:58)
at com.ebs.process_buy.doPost(process_buy.java:108)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:368)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:351)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:485)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Does that mean that GAE cannot work with JMS as JMS uses database connection and GAE needs to use their own cloud database? How can I work around this?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the full EMS provider URL in the form **tcp://host:port**. For example:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new TibjmsConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:7222");
```